# Pinterest share button functionality not working using react-share library

Tags: pinterest, react-share

`<PinterestShareButton url={localHostShareUrl}> <PinterestIcon size={35} round={true} /> </PinterestShareButton>`

I use this component to share blogs.I use facebook,twitter,linkedin and pininterst components using react-share.But when i click on pininterest button it doesn't popup share box but other platforms work smoothly.Anyone help me to figure this issue.Is this the problem with the package?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include both "url" and "media" parameters in the PinterestShareButton to create the pop up.

```
<PinterestShareButton url={url} media={url} description="">
 <PinterestIcon />
</PinterestShareButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share

For all react share buttons the URL is mandatory and in case of PinterestShareButton it requires a **media prop** as well.

[image]

[image]